# Virtualbox bridged adapter not working ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I need access to virtual machine from host machine terminal so I tried to setup **Bridged Adapter** between host and gust.

I did the following configurations but it still doesn't work.

[image: Virtualbox bridged adapter not working ubuntu]

Comment: "Bridged Adapter" is exactly what you do not want in your case. It means the VM uses its own network adapter to connect to the internet. Use "Host-Only" for a connection between host and client or use NAT if you want both connection between host and client AND internet access.

Comment: Is `openssh` setup in the guest?

Comment: @George Udosen, Yes it is

Comment: @derHugo "NAT Adapter" providing internet connectivity but i also need access to gust by ssh

Comment: It seems that your VM receives an ipv6 IP. How are you trying to connect via SSH?

Comment: @derHugo yes its using ipv6  i tryed to connect by ssh -6 , but it didn't work

main problem is i am not able to ping google from gust.  screenshot